# Formula of composite daily anomaly

Tags: mathematical-statistics, anomaly-detection, composite

If a daily anomaly is a difference between the daily mean from the corresponding daily climatology for the sought calendar day of the year, how to calculate the composite daily anomalies? Is there a general formula for it?

Comment: you have to define what a 'composite' daily anomaly is in statistical terms.

Comment: The composite is of multiple days associated with the anomaly. There are multiple dates in a certain period, and I'm trying to plot all daily anomalies in a figure, but not sure how to do it. Can I just take the average of all daily anomalies to find the composite?